# Split time range in 1 hour intervals

Tags: excel, vba

want to split a time range into 1 hour intervals

[image]

split the given time range into 1 hour intervals from cell A2 and A3, the time range will be changed  a serval time and on a (Macro) click it should split the given time range into 1 hour intervals.

Comment: FYI if you're using Excel365 this can be done with `SEQUENCE`

Comment: hey chris using Excel 2019

Comment: Possible in `Excel 2019` as well. try this : `=(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,(A3-A2)/TIME(1,,)+1))-1)*TIME(1,,)+A2`

Answer (score 1):

### Create an Hourly Sequence

```vb
Sub CreateHourlySequence()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim dt1: dt1 = ws.Range("A2").Value
    Dim dt2: dt2 = ws.Range("A3").Value
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = ws.Range("C2")
    dfCell.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - dfCell.Row + 1).ClearContents

    Select Case False
        Case IsDate(dt1), IsDate(dt2): Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Dim dtDiff As Long: dtDiff = DateDiff("h", dt1, dt2)
    
    Dim dtStart As Date, dStep As Long
    
    Select Case dtDiff
        Case Is > 0: dtStart = dt1: dStep = 1
        Case Is < 0: dtStart = dt2: dStep = -1
    End Select
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = Abs(dtDiff) + 1
    Dim Data() As Date: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim d As Long, r As Long
    
    If dStep = 0 Then
        Data(1, 1) = dtStart
    Else
        For d = 0 To dtDiff Step dStep
            r = r + 1
            Data(r, 1) = DateAdd("h", d, dtStart)
        Next d
    End If
    
    dfCell.Resize(rCount).Value = Data
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a non-VBA solution, then you have some options.

### Option 1: SEQUENCE

For the Excel version listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90), you could use the `SEQUENCE` function as suggested by chris neilsen.

Example:

Let's assume that your data starts at A1 like this:

[image]

Then, in C2, you could have :

`=SEQUENCE((A3-A2)/VALUE("01:00:00")+1,1,A2,VALUE("01:00:00"))`

Note that `VALUE("01:00:00")` represents 1 hour (but you could also use `TIME(1,,)` as suggested by [Mayukh Bhattacharya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8162520/mayukh-bhattacharya)).

---

### Option 2: Dynamic Array Formula

You have an Excel version listed [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531), you can use a dynamic array formula .

#### Example:

Making the same assumptions as option 1, for where the data is, you could use a formula like this one:

`=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(A3-A2)/VALUE("01:00:00")+1))-1)*VALUE("01:00:00")+A2`

##### Explanations:

Using the `INDIRECT` function inside the `ROW` function is a neat trick to get an array with consecutive values. For instance, `INDIRECT("1:9")` return the array containing rows 1 to 9 and passing it to `ROW` will return the array as a column like this `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}` (we get only one element per row).

Since we don't know in advance how many steps we will take we calculate the number of elements using `(A3-A2)/VALUE("01:00:00")+1` and concatenate it to `"1:"` to get the range of size that we need.

When we have the sequential array, we just need to make sure it starts by zero, which is why we remove 1 to all elements of the array like this:
`ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(A3-A2)/VALUE("01:00:00")+1))-1`

Finally, we multiply each element of the array by the value corresponding to 1 hour and add the starting point in `A2`.

---

### Option 3: Old array formula

Same idea as option 3 but using the old array formula explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#:%7E:text=Important%3A%20Press%20Ctrl%2BShift%2B,before%20you%20enter%20the%20formula.). Basically, you'll have to use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Comment: Hi DecimalTurn you can add two more in your answer: `=SEQUENCE((A3-A2)/TIME(1,,)+1,1,A2,TIME(1,,))` and one without volatile functions `=(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,(A3-A2)/TIME(1,,)+1))-1)*TIME(1,,)+A2`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, thanks I've added a remark about `TIME(1,,)`, but for the other volatile function, I think one example is sufficient since it's already a bit complicated for someone getting started with array functions.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple Solution given your example (to clear cells it is your job :-)
It would be better to write to an array but as example it should be ok.

```
Option Explicit
    
    Sub TimeToHour()
    Dim startTime As Double, endTime As Double, i As Double, z As Double
    startTime = Range("a2")
    endTime = Range("a3")
    Columns(3).NumberFormat = Range("a2").NumberFormat ' Column C
    z = 2
    For i = startTime To endTime Step 1 / 24
    Cells(z, 3) = i ' write to column c starting in row 2
    z = z + 1
    Next
    End Sub
```